# Using Filter::Util::Call to access the remainder of the calling source line in Perl

Tags: perl, source-filter

The following is a basic source filter that simply inserts a new line into the Perl source code at the point where it is `use`'d and then removes itself:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use 5.010;

{package insert;
    use Filter::Util::Call;
    BEGIN {$INC{'insert.pm'}++}
    sub import {
        my ($class, @data) = @_;
        filter_add sub {
            my $status = filter_read;
            if ($status) {
                $_ = "@data;$_";
                filter_del;
            }
            $status
        }
    }
}

my $x = 'init';
say $x;                             # init
use insert '$x = "hello"'; say $x;  # init (should be hello)
say $x;                             # hello
```

The problem, as shown in the comments at the end, is that any code following the terminal semicolon of the use statement, but still on the same line, ends up being compiled before the inserted source.

Am I using [Filter::Util::Call](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Filter%3a%3aUtil%3a%3aCall) incorrectly?  Is there some other way to setup the filter so that it will catch the first line?  Or is this just a limitation of Perl's source filtering mechanisms?

Comment: Is this a feature you need or just an oddity you've noticed?

Comment: A bit of both.  It seems that this usage of Filter::Util::Call is perfectly safe (no risk of trying to parse perl) but it has the obvious caveat mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

Filter::Util::Call does appear to be limited in the way you described. Perhaps this is an over-simplified example you gave, but is there any reason you can't just use a string eval instead of a source filter?

```
my $x = 'init';
say $x;                             # init
eval '$x = "hello"'; say $x;        # init (should be hello)
say $x;                             # hello
```